# SWIFT - reload UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift, nstimer

I have run into a problem when trying to reload my UITableView from within my TimersManager.swift file. The TimersManager.swift is used to control/manage all the timers in my to-do list/timers app. I am trying to update the UILabel to show the updated time as the timer ticks away. For some reason it will not update the table. Please have a look below and hopefully you can give me a nudge in the right direction. Thanks.

top of listTableViewController.swift:

```
var prepMgr: listTableViewController = listTableViewController()
var cell:customCell!

 class listTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

update func in listTableViewController: (this is called by another func in my TimersManager.swift file)

```
    func update (indexPathRow: Int) {

    for task in taskMgr.tasks {

        if task.timerOn == true {

        //calculate the time to display in 0:00:00 format.
        let date1 : NSDate = task.timerFinishDate
        let date2 : NSDate = NSDate()
        let compareResult = date1.compare(date2)
        let length = Int(round(date1.timeIntervalSinceDate(date2)))

        var tmpHours = length / 3600
        var tmpMinutes = (length % 3600) / 60
        var tmpSeconds = length % 60

        var timeString = "\(tmpHours):\(tmpMinutes):\(tmpSeconds)"

        println(task.subText) //test, display old value before update - WORKS

        taskMgr.updateTask(indexPathRow, name: taskMgr.tasks[indexPathRow].name, subText: timeString, timerOn: taskMgr.tasks[indexPathRow].timerOn, completed: taskMgr.tasks[indexPathRow].completed, timerFinishDate: taskMgr.tasks[indexPathRow].timerFinishDate, taskID: taskMgr.tasks[indexPathRow].taskID, sliderHours: taskMgr.tasks[indexPathRow].sliderHours, sliderMinutes:taskMgr.tasks[indexPathRow].sliderMinutes, sliderSeconds: taskMgr.tasks[indexPathRow].sliderSeconds)

            println(task.subText) //test, display updated value after update - WORKS
            println(timeString) //test, display time remaining in timer 0:00:00 - WORKS
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData() // DOES NOT UPDATE TABLE.

    }
}
```

the code for the NSTimer selector in TimersManager.swift:

```
    func tickTock (length:NSTimer!) {
    println(length.userInfo)

    var count = 0
    for timer in timers {

                let date1 : NSDate = timer.fireDate
                let date2 : NSDate = NSDate()
                let compareResult = date1.compare(date2)
                let length = Int(round(date1.timeIntervalSinceDate(date2)))

                if length <= 0 {
                        //Invalidate NSTimer
                        timer.myTimer.invalidate()
                        //Remove from array
                        timers.removeAtIndex(count)
                        }
        count++
        println(length) //test, shows how many seconds are left - WORKS

        //update labels.
       prepMgr.update(timer.indexPathRow) //Call to listTableViewController func - Half working, calls the function. updates the correct task. But table is not reloaded.

    }


    //update labels, reload table
    prepMgr.tableView.reloadData() //Test, Not working
}
```

Comment: And your "update" func gets called?

Comment: @derdida Yes, it does get called. The only part of the "update" func that does not work is the self.tableView.reloadData() part

Comment: Try to run it on the main thread: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
         prepMgr.tableView.reloadData()
        })

Comment: @derdida tried what you suggested, didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Can you post the project to github?

Comment: You could also use a NSNotification to handle the "Reload Function" of the Table. And just call them if you need an update of your table.

Comment: @derdida Lol, I was just coming back here to post that as the way I figured it out and saw your post :) If you want, post an answer with that and Ill mark it as accepted. :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a NSNotification to handle the "Reload Function" of the Table. And just call them if you need an update of your table.